# HTML range results to text file?

Tags: html, range

I want to output this range:

```
<form>
  <input type="range" name="points" min="0" max="10">
</form>
```

Into a text file called `results.txt`

Comment: can you use javascript?

Comment: @DCR Sure! I’ll maybe need something to C&P tho...


(I’m trash at JavaScript)

Comment: what backend are you using? php, node, python?

Comment: @DCR I’m not using a backend, but I’ll use PHP(I don’t know any PHP tho)

Comment: you need a backend to do this or you can write this to local storage

Comment: @DCR I have local storage.